# Change UINavigation bar shadow alpha issue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Trying to change the UINavigation bar shadow line and having an issue setting the alpha value.

This is currently not working:

```
let lineView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.alpha = 0.3
        view.layer.opacity = 0.3
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.3)
        return view
    }()

    addSubview(lineView)
    _ = lineView.anchor(nil, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 1)
```

What I'm getting is a solid white shadow color, not with setting the alpha.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Thanks

Comment: Alpha value is set but it's not visible in your design. I think you didn't understand the alpha correctly

Comment: I've set the alpha via lineView also which doesn't work.

Comment: If I set the value to 0.03 then the alpha is achieved. Why the need for the extra decimal value?

Comment: You have your alpha varying from 1.0 to 0.0. Here 1.0 represent totally opaque and 0.0 represent transparent and it varies in between. By the way you can read this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622417-alpha)

Comment: Yes, aware of alpha values - I left the alpha and layer opacity to indicate what I've tried. I've tried also setting the alpha via the lineView and this works, but instead of 0.3 I have to use 0.03.